# Hardcode an element only on a first block of similar elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <TopLevel>
    <Header>
      <!-- Header Information-->
    </Header>
    <!--Payments is a one to many-->
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>PID1</PaymentID>
      <!--More Info-->
      <!--Transactrion can be one to many for each payment-->
      <Transaction>
        <TranssID>TR1 - PID1</TranssID>
        <TranssID>TR2 - PID1</TranssID>
        <!--More Info-->
      </Transaction>
    </Payments>
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>PID2</PaymentID>
      <!--More Info-->
      <!--Transactrion can be one to many for each payment-->
      <Transaction>
        <TranssID>TR1 - PID2</TranssID>
        <TranssID>TR2 - PID2</TranssID>
        <!--More Info-->
      </Transaction>
    </Payments>
  </TopLevel>
</Document>
```

And here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <TopLevel>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Document/TopLevel/Payments"/>
    </TopLevel>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Payments">
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>
        <xsl:value-of select="PaymentID"/>
      </PaymentID>
      <ExtraColumn>
        <xsl:value-of select ="'ISO'" />
      </ExtraColumn>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Transaction"/>
    </Payments>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Transaction">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TranssID"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TranssID">
    <transIDs>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </transIDs>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which creates this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TopLevel>
  <Payments>
    <PaymentID>PID1</PaymentID>
    <ExtraColumn>ISO</ExtraColumn>
    <transIDs>TR1 - PID1</transIDs>
    <transIDs>TR2 - PID1</transIDs>
  </Payments>
  <Payments>
    <PaymentID>PID2</PaymentID>
    <ExtraColumn>ISO</ExtraColumn>
    <transIDs>TR1 - PID2</transIDs>
    <transIDs>TR2 - PID2</transIDs>
  </Payments>
</TopLevel>
```

My problem here is that, I only need to display the ExtraColumn on the first Payments Block and should not be displayed on the succeeding payments block.

Any Idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the correct answer below

```
  <xsl:template match="Payments">
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>
        <xsl:value-of select="PaymentID"/>
      </PaymentID>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <ExtraColumn>
          <xsl:value-of select ="'ISO'" />
        </ExtraColumn>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Transaction"/>
    </Payments>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You don't need the variable here, you can just say `<xsl:if test="position() = 1">`

Comment: oh ok thanks, just trying to play around with these functions then found it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  <xsl:template match="Payments">
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>
        <xsl:value-of select="PaymentID"/>
      </PaymentID>
      <ExtraColumn>
        <xsl:value-of select ="'ISO'" />
      </ExtraColumn>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Transaction"/>
    </Payments>
  </xsl:template>
```

use

```
  <xsl:template match="Payments[1]">
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>
        <xsl:value-of select="PaymentID"/>
      </PaymentID>
      <ExtraColumn>
        <xsl:value-of select ="'ISO'" />
      </ExtraColumn>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Transaction"/>
    </Payments>
  </xsl:template>
```

and

```
  <xsl:template match="Payments[position() &gt; 1]">
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>
        <xsl:value-of select="PaymentID"/>
      </PaymentID>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="Transaction"/>
    </Payments>
  </xsl:template>
```